# Aspect not working witha spring bean

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to create a simple aspect .
Here is my simple spring bean

```
public class SimpleService {
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

}
```

Here is my aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class SimpleAspect {
    @Before("execution(void sayHello())")
    public void entering(){
        System.out.println("entering..");
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
         <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="service" class="com.schatt.service.SimpleService"></bean>
```

My understanding was that when I try to invoke SimpleService.sayHello() , the before aspect will be called and after that sayHello() will be called.But the aspect is not getting triggered.Can not understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect needs to be created by Spring (in oder to apply the proxying).

```
<bean id="simpleAspect" class="package-name.SimpleAspect"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class does not implement any interface, you will have to use `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what *manish* and *fateddy* have said, please also note that `SimpleService` needs to be a Spring `@Component` in order to make it work with Spring AOP.